# Преобразование даты в INSERT INTO

Tags: mysql

В БД mysql дата храниться в формате `2012-04-30`, а при вставке она выглядит так: `30-04-2012`. Есть ли функция в mysql, которая на лету может преобразовать дату в нужный формат?

Answer (score 2):

есть

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2007-10-04 22:23:00', '%H:%i:%s');    -> '22:23:00'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Получилось!!!